# merge_exclude_columns in dbt incremental merge strategy not working as expected

Tags: sql, dbt, databricks-sql

I am trying to build an incremental merge model using dbt. My requirement is to exclude some columns from being updated when the dbt merge query runs.

I am using the dbt configuration, merge_*exclude*_columns like below,

```
{{
        config(
            tags = ['model_test'],
            unique_key = 'id',
            materialized = 'incremental',
            incremental_strategy = 'merge',
            merge_exclude_columns = ['method']
        )
    }}
```

The merge query being generated by dbt for this,

```
merge into target as DBT_INTERNAL_DEST
      using source_temp as DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE
      on DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.id = DBT_INTERNAL_DEST.id
      when matched then update set *
      when not matched then insert *
```

When I run the model using this configuration, I still see the method field being updated in the target table.

Can anyone help me understand what exactly is going wrong over here?

Answer (score 0):

I have it working (as designed I assume) using dbt 1.6.5 (make sure you have the latest version and are not overwriting the global macros like get_merge_sql).

However the result is:

```
    merge into target as DBT_INTERNAL_DEST
    using source_temp as DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE
    on DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.id = DBT_INTERNAL_DEST.id
    when matched then update set <col list minus merge_exclude_columns>
    when not matched then insert *
```

This does actually not meet my requirements (perhaps it is ok for you?) and I am looking for a way to exclude them also from the insert branch.